# How to display only the columns in a column chart using WinRTXamlToolkit?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am using WinRTXamlToolkit to create a histogram in UWP.
I'd like to hide almost all elements in the chart, but displaying only the columns, is that possible?

EDIT:
[image]

Is it hard to hide only the confusing numbers displays along x Axis

Comment: I'd like to hide elements like "Title" and "Legend" for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide legend of WPF Toolkit chart with more than one data series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595222/hide-legend-of-wpf-toolkit-chart-with-more-than-one-data-series)

Comment: Otherwise you can dig them out of the templates if you're determined enough.

Answer (score 1):

I second Chris's suggestion that you'll need some serious retemplating. IMHO it would make more sense to simply build your own chart with a few bottom-aligned rectangles. It will be easier, it will perform better and be more satisfying to accomplish than chipping at the full chart control to trim it down to what is essentially - a few bottom-aligned rectangles. Bonus points for doing it in Win2D or other Direct2D way that should allow you to get real-time update performance.

See sample Win2D chart rendering implementation at https://github.com/xyzzer/Win2DChartSample