# Remove Wpf Charting Legend

Tags: wpf, legend, wpftoolkit

Can anyone help with wpf toolkit charting control?

I want to remove the legend beside my chart, but I can't find the solution. Please help thanks.

```
<Window x:Class="CSV_Reader.Histogram_for_2Pgs"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSV_Reader"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Histogram_for_2Pgs" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <chartingToolkit:Chart Height="350" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="10,10,10,15" x:Name="ColumnChart1" Title="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="800" >
                <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries DependentValuePath="Value"  IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListView x:Name="HistogramLabel" Height="Auto" Width="800"  >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Label" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding label}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding description}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Appear" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding appear}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
            <Button x:Name="PrintWindow" Content="Print" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10" Margin="10" Click="PrintWindow_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="DescFilter" Content="Descending"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10" Margin="10" Click="Desc_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="AscFilter" Content="Ascending"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Padding="10" Margin="10" Click="Asc_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

[I wanted to remove the legend in the red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY9hX.png)

Thanks in advance

[image: I want to remove the circled legend]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide legend of WPF Toolkit chart with more than one data series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595222/hide-legend-of-wpf-toolkit-chart-with-more-than-one-data-series)

Comment: Hi @Fruchtzwerg , my Wpf can't support TargetType="datavis:Legend"...How to solve it?Thanks

Comment: Add the following namespace to your XAML: `xmlns:datavis="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"`.

Comment: Yes it works, Thanks @jsanalytics

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
    xmlns:dv="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:dvc="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

        <dvc:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="dv:Legend">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </dvc:Chart.LegendStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried *Константин Байдиков's* solution, and seems not working. The issue is with "Width" property that it doesn't exists, so I edited the solution:

```cs
<DVC:Chart.LegendStyle>
  <Style>
   <Setter Property="DocumentViewerBase.Width" Value="0" />
  </Style>
</DVC:Chart.LegendStyle>
```

This does the job properly for me.