# setup ColumnChart from WinRTXamlToolkit

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm trying to setup Column Chart from WinRTXamlToolkit.
Let me ask:

Is there any guide for charts from this lib? Or which way you found the easiest to learn using charts?

How can I put labels near axises? In points like on below image:

- P0: Times
- P1: States

How to move labels above chart (like on below image)?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Tylko przez wnikliwą analizę kodu źródłowego :(

Comment: @FilipSkakun dzieki ;] I put my "findings" in self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found "workarounds" (far away from perfection but works).

Below WinRTXamlToolkit = WXT

Fastest way (if you don't know WXT) is:

- hide WXT elements

  - title (just dont set it)
  - legend (see [Hide legend of WPF Toolkit chart with more than one data series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595222/hide-legend-of-wpf-toolkit-chart-with-more-than-one-data-series))
- create your own equivalent of above elements using native XAML (TextBlocks ..) and place it wherever you like

To get column colors for legend do

```
MethodInXamlBackingObject() {
   var paletteOfFirstColumn = ColumnChart.Palette[0];
   var columnFirstBrush = paletteOfFirstColumn["Background"];
}
```

BTW. tips where from to learn WXT:

- analyse sources of samples in WXT - these are very detailed
- analyse WXT behaviour with tool "WXT Debug Console" (included in demo app) - very powerfull
- read arts about WXT and WPF Toolkit (from which WXT is a fork)

Comment: Actually, it's ported from Silverlight toolkit, but that likely originated in WPF Toolkit first.

Comment: BTW, I find when people ask about customizing this old heap of code that they would usually achieve their results faster by writing their own charts from scratch like this one:
https://github.com/xyzzer/Win2DChartSample